# Complex conditional groupby in R

Tags: r, group-by

Here is the problem I am trying to solve.
I want to take table 1 to table 2.

Table 1 :

```
df
#       icustay_id           starttime             endtime vaso_rate vaso_amount
# 1          1 2019-09-10 13:20:00 2019-09-11 13:20:00         3    293.0896
# 2          1 2019-09-11 13:30:00 2019-09-12 01:20:00         9    602.9983
# 3          1 2019-09-14 16:40:00 2019-09-15 16:40:00         4    208.9360
# 4          2 2019-09-10 12:40:00 2019-09-13 13:20:00         2    864.1494
# 5          3 2019-09-10 01:20:00 2019-09-11 13:20:00         9    405.2939
```

Table 2 :

```
df
#       icustay_id           starttime             endtime vaso_rate vaso_amount
# 1          1 2019-09-10 13:20:00 2019-09-12 01:20:00         3    293.0896
# 2          1 2019-09-14 16:40:00 2019-09-15 16:40:00         4    208.9360
# 3          2 2019-09-10 12:40:00 2019-09-13 13:20:00         2    864.1494
# 4          3 2019-09-10 01:20:00 2019-09-11 13:20:00         9    405.2939
```

As you notice :
I am trying to build a function that will :

1. For every single unique patient (unique icustay_id), groupby icustay_id ONLY if the medication has been stopped for less than an hour.
2. When the row merges :
   Some columns will retain the same value (i.e. the patient identifiers)
   Some columns must be modified :
3. Keep the earlier starttime
4. Keep the latter  endttime
5. Average the vaso-rate
6. Sum the vaso-amount

To do so, I have decided to add another column identifier that takes the value 1 when the condition is met and when all the rows are verified, groupby (icustay_id and that new column)

My code as it is written however does not assign the appropriate ID in respect to the condition.

Here is the sample df creation code :

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(   
  icustay_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3),   
  starttime = as.POSIXct(c("2019-09-10 13:20", "2019-09-11 13:30",  "2019-09-14 16:40", "2019-09-10 12:40", "2019-09-10 01:20")),   
  endtime = as.POSIXct(c("2019-09-11 13:20", "2019-09-11 01:20", "2019-09-15 16:40", "2019-09-13 13:20", "2019-09-11 13:20")),   
  vaso_rate = sample(1:10, 5, replace = TRUE),   
  vaso_amount = runif(5, 0, 1000) 
)
```

Here is the function code that I have right now :

```
merge_pressor_doses <- function(df){
  df %>% arrange(icustay_id,starttime)
  for (i in unique(df$icustay_id))
    {
    for (j in which(df$icustay_id==i))
      {
      start <- df$starttime[as.numeric(j)+1]
      end <- df$endtime[as.numeric(j)]
      stopduration <- as.numeric(difftime(start, end, units = 'mins'))
      bool <- stopduration < 60
      df <- df%>%mutate(
          group = case_when(
            bool = TRUE ~ 1,
            bool = FALSE ~ 0)
          )
      }
  } 
  return(df)
}
```

This should result in :

```
df
#       icustay_id           starttime             endtime vaso_rate vaso_amount  group
# 1          1 2019-09-10 13:20:00 2019-09-11 13:20:00         3    293.0896      1
# 2          1 2019-09-11 13:30:00 2019-09-12 01:20:00         9    602.9983      1
# 3          1 2019-09-14 16:40:00 2019-09-15 16:40:00         4    208.9360      0
# 4          2 2019-09-10 12:40:00 2019-09-13 13:20:00         2    864.1494      1
# 5          3 2019-09-10 01:20:00 2019-09-11 13:20:00         9    405.2939      1
```

But in my case the 3rd row is assign a value of 1...

If I can manage to make this portion of the code work, I could proceed with this portion of the code to achieve my objective.

The eventual second portion of the code would be :

```
group_by(group, icustay_id) %>% 
  summarise(
    starttime = min(starttime), 
    endtime = max(endtime),
    vaso_rate = mean(vaso_rate),
    sum_vaso_amount = sum(vaso_amount))
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Out of curiosity, wouldn't it make sense to calculate weighted mean for rate istead of simple mean. Let's say there were two medications, one lasted 9 hours with rate 10, the other, shortly after, lasted 1 hour, with rate 1. Simple mean would be 5.5. But I'd say it's more like (10*9 + 1*1)/(9 + 1) = 9.1

Comment: Yes totally. I just wanted to simplify the problem to the maximum here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a new column `pause` which says how much time passed since the last medication. Then using this column we assign groups ids to medications: `cumsum(pause >= 1)` - start with 0, then if pause is >=1 hours, it's a different group.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(   
  icustay_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3),   
  starttime = as.POSIXct(c("2019-09-10 13:20", "2019-09-11 13:30",  "2019-09-14 16:40", "2019-09-10 12:40", "2019-09-10 01:20")),   
  endtime = as.POSIXct(c("2019-09-11 13:20", "2019-09-11 01:20", "2019-09-15 16:40", "2019-09-13 13:20", "2019-09-11 13:20")),   
  vaso_rate = sample(1:10, 5, replace = TRUE),   
  vaso_amount = runif(5, 0, 1000) 
)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <-
  df %>% 
  group_by(icustay_id) %>% 
  mutate(pause = difftime(starttime, lag(endtime), units = "hours")) %>% 
  replace_na(list(pause = 0)) %>% 
  mutate(vaso_id = cumsum(pause >= 1))

# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Groups:   icustay_id [3]
# icustay_id starttime           endtime             vaso_rate vaso_amount pause            vaso_id
# <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>                  <int>       <dbl> <drtn>             <int>
# 1          1 2019-09-10 13:20:00 2019-09-11 13:20:00         9       898.   0.0000000 hours       0
# 2          1 2019-09-11 13:30:00 2019-09-11 01:20:00         4       945.   0.1666667 hours       0
# 3          1 2019-09-14 16:40:00 2019-09-15 16:40:00         7       661.  87.3333333 hours       1
# 4          2 2019-09-10 12:40:00 2019-09-13 13:20:00         1       629.   0.0000000 hours       0
# 5          3 2019-09-10 01:20:00 2019-09-11 13:20:00         2        61.8  0.0000000 hours       0
```

Then we can use the code you provided.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(icustay_id, vaso_id) %>% 
  summarise(
    starttime = min(starttime), 
    endtime = max(endtime),
    vaso_rate = mean(vaso_rate),
    sum_vaso_amount = sum(vaso_amount)
  )

# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   icustay_id [3]
# icustay_id vaso_id starttime           endtime             vaso_rate sum_vaso_amount
# <dbl>   <int> <dttm>              <dttm>                  <dbl>           <dbl>
# 1          1       0 2019-09-10 13:20:00 2019-09-11 13:20:00       6.5          1843. 
# 2          1       1 2019-09-14 16:40:00 2019-09-15 16:40:00       7             661. 
# 3          2       0 2019-09-10 12:40:00 2019-09-13 13:20:00       1             629. 
# 4          3       0 2019-09-10 01:20:00 2019-09-11 13:20:00       2              61.8
```

Comment: This is genius!!!! Thank you very much. Smart approach to group_by right from the start and manipulate the dataframe by id this way. I was not aware of the pause function. Great learning today!